# Angular Library Project npm linked navigate to source instead d.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, webstorm, tsconfig

My Project structure:

```
Root Folder
 - Lib1
 - Lib2
 - App
```

`Lib1` and `Lib2` is being being build with `--watch` flag. `Lib2` is using Components of `Lib1` and `App` is using a Component of `Lib2`. The libraries are linked with npm link.

Livereload of the app and library works just fine. My problem is in the IDE when I open a Lib2 Component and navigate to a Lib1 Component in the IDE, I jump to the `d.ts` files in the `dist` folder instead of the source file.

How can I achieve navigation to the source files instead of definition files?